# Closed form of $\int_1^2\sqrt\frac{x^6+4x^4-2x^3+1}{x^4}\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Find the exact value (closed form) of:

$\displaystyle\int_1^2\sqrt\frac{x^6+4x^4-2x^3+1}{x^4}\ \mathrm dx$

I do not really know where to start, so please forgive me for not showing my attempt.

Wolfram alpha gives $2.27986$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha Pro also doesn't show any steps :/

Comment: The integral doesn't look as if it may be determined in terms of standard mathematical functions (which isn't too surprising) and this means that you would need to do a numerical integration

Comment: @jim Cleo will deal with it with her $\operatorname{Li}$ and etc.

Comment: Just quoting from Wolfram

Comment: @KennyLau What is "Li"?

Comment: More than dilogarithms, incomplete elliptic integrals are involved here. Do you *really* need a closed form, or you are fine with a representation given by a fast-convergent series/ a good numerical approximation?

Comment: i think there is no closed form for this integral

Comment: That can be written as:
$$ I=\int_{1}^{2}dx\,\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2+4} $$
where $x-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a smooth and increasing function on the interval $(1,2)$, bounded by $1$. Numerical approximations are not difficult.

Comment: Where does it come from??

Comment: @qbert Logarithmic integral

Comment: Since this just came up in the reopen queue: as long as OP does not even reply to "Do you really need a closed form, or you are fine with a representation given by a fast-convergent series/ a good numerical approximation?" I really do not see why this should be reopened. It is not even clear what "Find the value" should mean precisely.

Comment: @quid sorry, added.